# Infinite while loop while renaming file(Qt C++)

Tags: c++, qt

I've made a if else structure that checks if a file exist or not. If it does it should go into a while loop and add a integer and check again if the file exist. It should work the same as broswer does of Windows like `"filename (1).ext"`. I have the following code:

```
    QFile file("messages/" + name + ".txt");

    if(!file.exists())
    {
        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        qDebug() << "file doesn't exist, saving complete";
        QTextStream message_file(&file);
        message_file << body;
        file.close();
        QMessageBox::about(0,"Succes!","Uw bericht is opgeslagen en verstuurd!");
    }

    else {
        int n = 0;

        qDebug() << "file does exist";

        while(file.exists()){
            n++;
            QString nstring = QString::number(n);
            qDebug() << "file exists sequence:  " + nstring;
            QFile file("messages/" + name + " (" + nstring +").txt");
        }

        file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
        QTextStream message_file(&file);
        message_file << body;
        file.close();
        QMessageBox::about(0,"Succes!","Uw bericht is opgeslagen en verstuurd!");
    }
```

But this code just overwrites to original file, with the original file name (of course). So it seems like it doesnt change the path of `QFile file`. I do get this with `qDebug()` uptil infinite:

```
file exists sequence: 1
file exists sequence: 2
so on..
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you think should break the loop here?        while(file.exists()){
            n++;
            QString nstring = QString::number(n);
            qDebug() << "file exists sequence:  " + nstring;
            QFile file("messages/" + name " (" + nstring +").txt");
        }

Comment: Well I thought that n changes the file name each iteration. And the loop checks every iteration if the file excist. So I thought it should go on until there is a file name that doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that inside your while loop you are creating a local variable named file, which doesn't actually change the file that you're calling exists() on.

```
int n = 1;
while (n) int n = 0;
```

will never terminate, it needs to be:

```
int n = 1;
while (n) n = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are [shadowing a variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing).

```
    while(file.exists()){
        n++;
        QString nstring = QString::number(n);
        qDebug() << "file exists sequence:  " + nstring;
        QFile file("messages/" + name + " (" + nstring +").txt");
    }
```

It seems as though you've mixed up assignment and declaration.

```
QFile file;
```

declares a new variable called file at the current scope.

```
int i = 1;
{
    int i = 2;
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Prints "2" and then "1".

What's actually happening in your code is this:

```
    while(outer::file.exists()){
        n++;
        QString inner::nstring = QString::number(n);
        qDebug() << "file exists sequence:  " + inner::nstring;
        QFile inner::file("messages/" + name + " (" + inner::nstring +").txt");
    }
```

You could instead do:

```
    while(file.exists()){
        n++;
        QString nstring = QString::number(n);
        qDebug() << "file exists sequence:  " + nstring;
        file.open("messages/" + name + " (" + nstring +").txt");
    }
```